# Rollover Images Not Working - Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: html, css, image, dreamweaver, rollover

So I made some .png's in Photoshop and made rollover images with them just by going through Insert > Image Objects > Rollover Image. They worked perfectly for weeks but all of the sudden stopped working, both the rollover effect and the actual hyperlink attached to that social media URL. When you use the Rollover Image function it turns `<body>` into:

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/facebook2.png','images/instagram2.png','images/twitter2.png','images/tumblr2.png','images/threadflip2.png','images/pintrest2.png','images/laceandlattes_title2.png')">
```

The string of HTML for each individual icon looks something like this, within a div tag:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ssaammrr" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('facebook','','images/facebook2.png',1)"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="30" height="30" id="facebook" /></a>
```

It seems right to me but if anybody may have an idea as to why this is failing, please let me know

Comment: Its an old Technique, Why can't you do it with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of floored that Dreamweaver CS6, released in April of 2012, is still using JavaScript to swap images. This is far easier and more efficient with just CSS and some extra markup.

I'm ripping this answer from [one of my earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19891306/1883647) on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19891138/1883647) (that is tangentially related to yours) to show an example of how to do this with CSS.

Say you have the following markup:

```
<a class="rollover-container">
    <img class="rollover" src="images/facebook.png"/>
    <img class="rollover-swap" src="images/facebook2.png"/>
</a>
```

I have some classes on the elements already, for the rollover effect. There is a containing `<a>` element that holds two `<img>` elements. This allows you to click on the image regardless of what state they're in and be linked to the desired page (you would add an `href` onto the `<a>` for wherever you want to go). You can then populate the `src` attributes on the `<img>`s with whatever images you want (`.rollover` is shown by default, and `.rollover-swap` is hidden, but is swapped in on hover).

Using this markup, you can include the following CSS to achieve an image swapping effect with only CSS:

```
/* Initially hide the hover image */
.rollover-swap {
    display: none;
}

/* When hovering over the <a> container, hide the default image */
.rollover-container:hover .rollover {
    display: none;
}

/* When hovering over the <a> container, show the hover image */
.rollover-container:hover .rollover-swap {
    display: inline;
}
```

You can see a JSFiddle demo of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5KdQg/1/) (with some additional but harmless markup, since this demo was originally for that other question).

This method should not need any JavaScript, so it can be removed (i.e. remove your `onload`, `onmouseout`, and `onmouseover` attributes from your elements).

Comment: @user3075558 Did you keep the JS event handlers on the elements? Those should be removed if you're trying this method.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine in Dreamweaver, to trouble shoot this further I would make sure that you have the following js functions in your head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
```